# MySQL to HBase using Sqoop: Driver issue

Tags: mysql, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, sqoop

I am new to Sqoop. I am trying to import data from MySQL to hbase. That's why have to use Database connector for MySQL. Path to my connector file is `/usr/lib/sqoop2/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar` at server. Database name is :`testhadoop` and table which i am using is `employee` the command i enter is as

```
root@server:~# sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql//localhost/testhadoop --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --username root --table mytable
```

After hitting Enter key, i have to enter root password. And then a long long error message come

```
13/09/12 17:39:16 WARN sqoop.ConnFactory: Parameter --driver is set to an
 explicit driver however appropriate connection manager is not being set 
(via --connection-manager). Sqoop is going to fall back to org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager. Please specify explicitly which connection manager should be used next time.
        13/09/12 17:39:16 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
        13/09/12 17:39:16 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
        13/09/12 17:39:16 ERROR manager.SqlManager: 
        Error executing statement: java.sql.SQLException: 
        No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql//localhost/testhadoop
```

Please tell me how to get rid of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the command line it seems that you are using Sqoop 1.x whereas the JDBC driver is in path for Sqoop2. I would recommend to copy the jar file mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar to /usr/lib/sqoop/lib instead, so that it's available for Sqoop 1.

Also I would strongly suggest to drop the parameter --driver as it will force Sqoop to use Generic JDBC Connector instead of the specialized MySQL connector.